# Using magento's contact form create a contact form with 4 fields with the use of Javascript or others to create more

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, javascript, forms, contact-us

I'm working on a contact form within magento to work as an artwork upload after ordering so you can send the artwork for the banners. It'll have the follow fields

`Item SKU, Image Name, Upload`

It would be these 3 that been to be repeated when the user clicks a button to add more.

I've setup a template within magento and made changes to the contact form to get additional fields working but 2 of the same type also seem to create issues.

Here an example of what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

I don'T understang 100% your problem, but in HTML and forms you need to have unique names and ids of your input elements.

So either you do something like `name="itemSku[]"` or (recommended) you define the array key `name="itemSku[42]"`, so you have the item sku, image name and file together.